# Can I be forced to do extra responsibilities?

Tags: job-description

I have been a stand in for our Quality Specialist for more than a year. It has never been long periods of time but since March I have been doing her work consecutively, with my own work in between.
Due to the high workload my quality dropped for my normal BAU so I requested not to do her work anymore. (She is constantly being pulled out for projects or she doesn't have capacity to do all her work as she has to play catch up.)
My manager doesn't want to accept this and now wants me to take on more of the QA's duties in order for me to be pulled out of my team and just focus on her work so that the quality of my work is not affected anymore. 
Her job grade is higher than mine and a promotion for me is not a option.

Comment: You have the same two choices every morning:  Do the work you're assigned, or find another position.  No one is "forcing" you to make either choice, but those are the choices you have.

Comment: What's your contract say?

Answer (score 1):

If they want you to "drop" your current duties, then demand the promotion that comes along with it.

If they refuse and still want you to do this job, then your only options are to either do it or find a new job.

Comment: You may want to consider the fact that if the OP puts his concerns in the form of a demand, one of those two options may immediately be off the table.